# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PushDeploymentController'

Tags: azure-functions, gitlab-ci

We are publishing the application to function app from GitLab and giving the below error. So could  help to guide how to resolve this?

```
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 28.06 MB []Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 28.06 MB []Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 28.06 MB []Error uploading archive (InternalServerError).
Server Response: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PushDeploymentController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Access to the path 'C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\deployment' is denied.","ExceptionType":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at System.IO.Abstractions.DirectoryWrapper.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.FileSystemHelpers.CreateDirectory(String path) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Infrastructure\\FileSystemHelpers.cs:line 32\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Environment.get_DeploymentTracePath() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Environment.cs:line 297\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Web.App_Start.NinjectServices.GetLogger(IEnvironment environment, IKernel kernel) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services.Web\\App_Start\\NinjectServices.cs:line 775\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Web.App_Start.NinjectServices.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<RegisterServices>b__13(IContext context) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services.Web\\App_Start\\NinjectServices.cs:line 280\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.CallbackProvider`1.CreateInstance(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)\r\n   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `System.InvalidOperationException` exception which happens for the invalid parameters.

As it is written on the server response, please make sure that the controller has `pubic` as it's access control and it doesn't have any arguments.

It's private access control maybe the reason for denial access to path.

Comment: Yes, It is hosted in a private network. So after adding the application setting as 
WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1 and resolving the issue

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was the one provided by BSG in a comment above.
I had to set `WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET` to `1` in the Application Settings for the function.

I'm mainly providing an answer here so i can comment my stack trace in case anyone else runs into this in the future.

---

The outer exception was the same:
`"ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DeploymentController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."`.

The inner exception had this:  `"ExceptionMessage":"Access to the path 'C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\deployment' is denied."`